Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, 7.B.20 part (a)
I'm trying to solve part (a) of the following problem (from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th Edition, problem 20 of section 7B) where $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space and $T^*$ is the adjoint of operator $T$:

Suppose $T \in \mathscr L(V)$ is normal and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant
under $T$.
(a) Prove that $U^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T$.
(b) Prove that $U$ is invariant under $T^{*}$.
(c) Prove that $(T|_U)^*=(T^*)|_U$.
(d) Prove that $T|_U \in \mathscr L(U)$ and $T|_{U^{\perp}} \in \mathscr L(U^{\perp})$ are normal operators.
This exercise can be used to give yet another proof of the complex spectral
theorem (use induction on dim  and the result that  has an eigenvector).

Now I have proved (a) for the case where $V$ is a complex inner product space by using the following fact (problem 7.B.9):

Suppose $ = $ and $T \in \mathscr L(V)$. Prove that $T$ is normal if and only if there
exists a polynomial $p \in \mathscr P()$ such that $T^*=p(T)$.

But I don't have any idea how to prove the real case. Even the proven complex case is not satisfactory since Axler mentions at the end of the problem that the exercise can be used to give an alternative proof of the complex spectral theorem while the above fact that was used in the proof uses the complex spectral theorem for its own proof making it a circular argument.
I came across this link but the proof uses traces that are not discussed at this point in Axler's book. So in short I need a proof that does not use trace, covers both the real and complex case and does not rely on the complex spectral theorem itself.
Thanks in advance.

If $p(T)=T^,$ where $T$ is a real valued matrix then $\tilde{p}( T)=T^,$ for $\tilde{p}(x)={\rm Re} ,p(x)$ and $\tilde{p}$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.

(a) $U$ is invariant under $T$ means that $u \in U \implies Tu \in U$. $U^\perp = {v \in V: \langle u, v \rangle =0 , ;  \forall  u \in U }$ and for $v \in U^\perp$, $\langle Tv, u \rangle = \langle v , T^* u \rangle$. Since $\operatorname{range}T=\operatorname{range}T^$  (7.21(b)), $T^ u \in U$ and therefore $\langle v , T^* u \rangle=0$, i.e. $U^\perp$ is invariant under $T$.

@TedBlack you said "since range $T$=range $T^*$, $T^*u \in U$", but you can't make that conclusion since $U$ being invariant under $T$ does not translate into range $T=U$.

$U$ is invariant under $T$ if $Tu \in U$ for every $u \in U$ (Definition 5.2). Even if $\operatorname{range} T \subset U$ it means every element of $Tu \in U$. So if $\operatorname{range} T^*=\operatorname{range} T$ then for every $u \in U$, $T^*u \in U$.

@TedBlack There is no justification for "range $T \subset U$", as a counterexample consider the self-adjoint (hence normal) identity operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the $x$-axis is invariant under $I$ while obviously the range of identity operator being the whole plane isn't a subset of it.

This is the definition of an invariant subspace! The question has two conditions: (i) $T$ is a normal operator (ii) $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$.

@TedBlack you are misinterpreting $U$ being invariant to mean "range $T \subset U$" while these are two different things: range $T \subset U$ means $Tv \in U, \forall v \in V$ while $U$ being invariant means $Tu \in U, \forall u \in U$.

I understand that for $v \in V$ it does not mean that $Tv \in U$! It is the restriction of $T$ in $U$ has the property $\operatorname{range} T\vert_U = \operatorname{range} T^*\vert_U$ (i.e. $T\vert_U$ is also a normal operator). I will refrain from any further exchanges.

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_m$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ and let $e_{m+1}, \ldots, e_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$, so that $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$. Because $U$ is invariant under $T$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is of the form
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,m} & A_{1,m+1} & \cdots & A_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{m,1} & \cdots & A_{m,m} & A_{m,m+1} & \cdots & A_{m,n} \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & A_{m+1,m+1} & \cdots & A_{m+1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & A_{n,m+1} & \cdots & A_{n,n} \\
\end{pmatrix}. $$
It follows that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^m ||T e_k||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m |A_{j,k}|^2. \tag{1} $$
Furthermore, since $A^*$ is the matrix of $T^*$ with respect to $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ and $|\overline{z}| = |z|$ for any $z \in \mathbf{C}$,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^m ||T^* e_k||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |A_{k,j}|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m |A_{j,k}|^2. \tag{2} $$
Since $T$ is normal we have $||T e_k||^2 = ||T^* e_k||^2$ for each $k$ and thus by subtracting (1) from (2) we find that
$$ 0 = \sum_{k=m+1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m |A_{j,k}|^2, $$
which gives us $A_{j,k} = 0$ for all $k \in \{ m+1, \ldots, n \}$  and all $j \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}$, so that
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,m} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{m,1} & \cdots & A_{m,m} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & A_{m+1,m+1} & \cdots & A_{m+1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & A_{n,m+1} & \cdots & A_{n,n} \\
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Thus $U^\perp$ is invariant under $T$.

Thank you, just a small typo in (2): the middle expression is $A^*$, otherwise perfect.

I skipped a few steps in that line for brevity; I am using $$ |(A^*){j,k}|^2 = \left|\overline{A{k,j}}\right|^2 = |A_{k,j}|^2. $$ The indices of the summation get swapped for the next equality.
